# Extracting hash value from a multi-dimenisonal array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array, nokogiri

I am parsing HTML into an array as shown below.  I can get the data into the array and then push the data into the database. One row of the array data is:

```
{:address=>"6222 Lodgepole Dr", :members=>["Diana L Dillard", "Kemberly J Williams", "George S Williams Iii"]}
```

The database result is:

```
Master                 Neighbor                     Name

7545 XYZ Dr     --- - 8283 Southern Watch Pl    --- - - Diana L Dillard - Kemberly J Williams - George S Williams Iii
```

These are my questions:

1. How do I get the `Address.create` loop to only insert the first member from the array, in this example `Diana L Dillard`, into the "name" field instead of all the names?  Ideally I want to create one field for the first and then another for all others.
2. Why do I get these dashes "---" inserted with my data?  I do not want them.

This is my current code:

```
url = "XYZ"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

results = []

# parse .single tags
doc.css('.single').each do |single_div|

  res = {}
  res[:address] = single_div.at_css('span.address').text
  res[:members] = single_div.css('li.basic_info').collect{|el| el.text.strip}
  results << res
end

results.each do|address|
  puts "#{address}: #{members}"
  Address.create(:neighboradd => "#{address}", :master => '7545 XYZ Dr', :name => "{members}")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
results.each do |address|
  puts "#{address}: #{members}"
  Address.create(
    :neighboradd => "#{address}",
    :master => '7545 XYZ Dr',
    :name => "{members}"
  )
end
```

Should be something like

```
results.each do |res|
  puts "#{res[:address]}: #{res[:members]}"
  Address.create(
    :neighboradd => res[:address],
    :master => '7545 XYZ Dr',
    :name => res[:members].join(', ') # this should be "#{res[members]}"? (with "#")
  )
end
```

The `---` is because you were using the whole hash for `:neighboradd`.

If you want only the first member:

```
    :name => res[:members].first
```

Comment: Thank you.  Looks so simple now.  I had tried .first but not properly because I was not using 'res'